# failed to create directory :Android

Tags: java, android

when opening project after Syncing it gives me this message i checked the SDK
also

```
error: failed to create directory 'C:\tmp\T06.10-Exercise-EditTextPreferenceConstraints\app\generated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed my c\Users\username after that studio didn't work because the path of the old username changed after restart every thing is fine